# Customised masterpage not honoured by iOS on iPad

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I created a totally blank white masterpage by cloning v4.master and adding style="display:none" to hide all the SharePoint screen elements I wanted to hide.

I then set my particular web page to use this master.

Everything is great on IE9, FF and Chrome. However, when viewed in Safari on an iPad (not using Mobile View) all of the SharePoint navigation elements are displayed regardless.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2007, 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Ooops sorry. SharePoint Online, so 2010. Thx.

Comment: Have you tried setting this with javascript instead?